# doctrine odm embedded documents wont load automatically

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, odm

I have this basic document and embedded document inside it i took it from the official [doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/embedded-mapping.html)

```
User:
  type: document
  embedOne:
    address:
      targetDocument: Address

Address:
  type: embeddedDocument
```

When i load the user document i expect the address to be loaded as well but instead the property is empty.

How can i tell doctrine to load all the embedded documents?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What data is coming from database? Have you cleared the cache if the field was added just before?

Comment: @malarzm only the parent document is been hydrated, the address embedded document is not, i clear the cache nothing happens

Comment: Unfortunately don't know what might be wrong, normally single embedded documents are hydrated immediately.